# Using a bounding polygon, instead of a bounding box

Tags: python, sql

I've got a large set of LAT/LON coordinates. Up until now, when I needed to select out those that fell within a certain region, I'd just create a bounding box using some MINx, MAXx, MINy, MAXy values and try to get it as close as possible to the area I was interested in.

I'd like to get more precise by using more than 4 points as the extent of my search area, in this specific case, 14 points.

I'll probably be using Python or SQL for this, so the specific syntax on any solution isn't that important, I'm just interested in the formula for figuring this one out.

Comment: You might find discussions about concave and convex hulls to be relevant: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22concave+hull%22+%22convex+hull%22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Shapely](http://gispython.org/shapely/docs/1.2/manual.html%20Shapely) to perform the operation (e.g. [within](http://gispython.org/shapely/docs/1.2/manual.html#object.within%20within)).  You could load both geometries via one Shapely's methods for [interoperation](http://gispython.org/shapely/docs/1.2/manual.html#interoperation%20interoperation).

Answer (score 2):

PostGIS has a [collection of relational operators](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.5/reference.html#Spatial_Relationships_Measurements) that should do what you want.

Comment: SELECT * FROM pointstable, polygonstable
WHERE st_intersects(pointstable.geom, polygonstable.geom)=TRUE

Comment: specifically: [`ST_Contains`](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/ST_Contains.html) or [`ST_Within`](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/ST_Within.html) (possibly [`ST_DWithin`](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/ST_DWithin.html) if you want to overcompensate for rounding errors)